# Print statements with objects. Java

Tags: java, object

I am currently writing a program that models an employee as a way to get started in object oriented programming. It gets a name, hire date, and address of each employee, and then must display the information

My current program has no compile errors, but I am confused as to how I would go about printing the information in a neat manner. Thanks!

```
public class Unit10Assignment1
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
{
    int numEmployees = Input.getInt("How many employees are you storing?");
    Employee database[] = new Employee[numEmployees];

    for( int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++ )
    {
        String firstName = Input.getString("What is an employee's first name?");
        String lastName = Input.getString("What is their last name?");

        String street = Input.getString("What street do they live on?");
        String city = Input.getString("What city do they live in?");
        String state = Input.getString("What state do they live in?(2 characters)");
        String zip = Input.getString("What is their zipcode?");

        int month = Input.getInt ("In what month was he/she hired?(number)");
            int day = Input.getInt ("On what day was he/she hired(number)");
            int year = Input.getInt ("In what year was he/she hired?(number)");

        database[i] = new Employee(firstName, lastName, street, city, state, zip, month, day, year);
    }
}
}

class Employee
{
Name Name;
Address Address;
Date Date; 

Employee( String firstName, String lastName, String street, String city, String state, String zip, int month, int day, int year)
{
    Name = new Name( firstName, lastName );
    Address = new Address( street, city, state, zip );
    Date = new Date( month, day, year );
}
}

class Name
{
    String firstName = " ";
    String lastName = " ";

public Name(String newFirstName, String newLastName)
{
    firstName = newFirstName;
    lastName = newLastName;
}

public String getFirst()
{
    return firstName;
}
public String getLast()
{
    return lastName;
}
}

class Address
{
String street = " ";
String city = " ";
String state = " ";
String zip = " ";

public Address(String newStreet, String newCity, String newState, String newZip)
{
    street = newStreet;
    city = newCity;
    state = newState;
    zip = newZip;
}

public String getStreet()
{
    return street;
}

public String getCity()
{
    return city;
}

public String getState()
{
    return state;
}

public String getZip()
{
    return zip;
}
}

class Date
{
int month = 0;
int day = 0;
int year = 0;

public Date(int newMonth, int newDay, int newYear)
{
    month = newMonth;
    day = newDay;
    year = newYear;
}

public int getMonth()
{
    return month;
}

public int getDay()
{
    return day;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}


}
```

Having trouble formatting, hopefully you can understand it. If there are any problems with my current code, pointing them out to me would be appreciated. Also, my instructor uses his own class to get user input so no need to worry about that.

Comment: add a method in your `Employee` that will print all the information from the object.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I didn't think it was that simple haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For pretty printing an objects contents, I prefer overriding the toString method.

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `toString`-method in `Name`, `Address` and `Date`, and let `Employee` use these methods in its own `toString`.

E.g:

#### Name

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

#### Address

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return street + ", " + city + ", " + state + ", " + zip;
}
```

#### Date

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(month) + "." +
           String.valueOf(day)   + "." +
           String.valueOf(year);
}
```

#### Employee

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name.toString() + "\n" +
           date.toString() + "\n" +
           address.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

by the way, you can use astyle to format your code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It is the answer to this part of the question: "Having trouble formatting".
Just wanted to help in trouble - isn't it what this site intended to? By the way, I suppose topic starter could decide was it answer or not, without your help. 
Not to give advices if you don't asked to - so easy and so polite rule... But I respect any cultural differences though.