# Why can't I convert a object to string?

Tags: spring

I'm trying to save an object into a database table but when the record is saved the `name` value is empty. I'm using Spring and Hibernate.

When I log the object in the `MovieController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Movie createMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie){
    System.out.println(movie.toString());
    return movieService.createMovie(movie);
}
```

I see this value being logged.

> com.movieseat.models.Movie@abee456

What I would expect is

> id: 20, name: Star Wars

In my `app.component.ts` I have:

```
createMovie(movie: Movie): void {
  this._dataService.createMovie<Movie>({'id': 20, 'name': 'Star Wars'})
  .subscribe((data) => this.movie = data,
  error => () => {
      'something went wrong';
  },
  () => {
      console.log(this.movies);
  });
}
```

The `app.service.ts`

```
public createMovie<T>(movie: Movie): Observable<T> {
    console.log(movie);
    return this.http.post<T>('/api/movies/', movie);
}
```

So why is the System out returning the object and not the values in the object? Or at least I think that's what it's doing.

Comment: How did you define `toString()` for `Movie`?

Comment: @doelleri `System.out.println(movie.toString());` It's in the first code block.

Comment: Override `toString` in your `Movie` class.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma That's how you're calling it, not defining it.

Comment: Ah in that case I have not defined it. Could you give a lead on how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when to use toString() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329168/when-to-use-tostring-method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print statements with objects. Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996953/print-statements-with-objects-java)

Answer (score 2):

Overridding `toString` is fairly easy. You can use your IDE to generate the code automatically, or just write it out.

In your example something like this may be all you need:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "id: " + id + "name: " + name;
}
```

Essentially what you're doing is the same thing you would do with `System.out.println` to print out the values of the object, only in this case the `toString` method provides a default handler on what properties you want printed so you don't need to specify them each time. Functionally this is equivalent to doing

```
System.out.println("id: " + movie.getId() + "name: " + movie.getName());
```

but, as you're likely to call the same print statement multiple times, it would become a pain to update each print statement to add a new parameter called Description.

At any rate - it's a best practice to override `toString` to print out your object for a variety of reasons (all subject to much discussion), but primarily it has helped me with debugging, as you're finding out first hand.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Movie.java and generate the toString method.

I suggest you make use of your IDE's features to generate it. Don't hand-code it.

if you are using Intellij press ALT + Insert and generate toString then try with

System.out.println(movie);